# Can you tell what's going on in this clip? Is it obvious?

Tags: sound-design, test, employability, feedback, project

I was given an assignment by a prospective employer to test my sound design skills. They gave me a short, 2-paragraph description of a scene and then gave me three days to create the scene with sound. I was told to create it such that somebody could listen to it without being coached and tell what's happening. It was a challenging and fun project to do, and I think I did a decent job.

I'd love to hear your feedback, though. Can you tell what's going on? Is it reasonably unambiguous? I'd love to hear thoughts from fellow sound designers.

Listen to it [here](https://soundcloud.com/geekisthenewcool/sound-design-scene).

Answer (score 1):

Someone was sitting down to a drink with his faithful dog, when a UFO appeared. It may have done something to the dog or just floated around for a bit before leaving. Then after a few seconds of seeming normalcy, the UFO came back and adbucted the man. The last few seconds are of him inside the spaceship, breathing heavily.

Comment: All but the last little bit are pretty much dead-on to the script. Thanks for commenting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey cool..... even i have created such a track, telling a story only through sound for my personal learning.. will post it soon.

will listen to your track on speakers and reply soon

Comment: i look forward to hearing it!